# Materialize CSS Sidenav load content depending form nav selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am using **MaterializeCSS** to design a landing page for my company.

Now I have integrated a sidebar on the left side with three items. 
If a item is clicked, I want to load the specific content on the right. That content could be another HTML page or a website.

How Can I do that with the Materialize framework?

Here my html code:

```
  <body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a class="brand-logo center">Monitoring Tool</a>
                <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Side Navigation -->  
            <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
                <li class="logo">
                    <a class="brand-logo not-active">
                        <object id="front-page-logo" type="image/png" data="img/logo.png"></object>
                    </a></li>
                <p class="divider" id="logo-divider"></p>
                <li class="bold"><a id="nagios">Nagios</a></li>
                <li class="bold"><a id="munin">Munin</a></li>
                <li class="bold"><a id="usv-monitor">USV-Monitor</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>    
    </header>

    <main>
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen id="iframe"></iframe>
    </main>

   <footer class="page-footer">
    </footer>
    <!--  Scripts-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>

</body>
```

Thanks A Lot!

Comment: Try `ui-router` you can call different view content for each sidenav menu

Comment: I am not sure, but isn't `ui-router` only a element in Angular?

Comment: Sorry my bad, was thinking you are using angular material. In this case you can use jquery ajax and have the sidenav menu load the content onclick, and show the ajax result in the right page content.

Comment: Try jQuery library to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something? Just use the `href` and `target` attributes of the `a` element. Like this:

```
<a id="nagios" href="http://path/to/nagios/" target="iframe">Nagios</a></li>
<a id="munin" href="http://path/to/munin/" target="iframe">Munin</a></li>
<a id="usv-monitor" href="http://path/to/usv-monitor/" target="iframe">USV-Monitor</a></li>

<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen id="iframe" name="iframe"></iframe>
```